# Is it safe to just close laptop lid before carrying it? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hardware-failure

I have a Windows 10 laptop with a (mechanical) hard drive.  Is it safe to just close the lid before carrying a computer around in a bag?  My worry is that it will wake up, the hard disk will turn on, and will get damaged while being carried around.

I have little experience with Windows 10.  The last version of Windows I used was Windows XP years ago.  At that time I always manually hibernated my laptop as it would occasionally wake up from sleep.  I did not trust the HDD to stay off when the computer was in sleep mode.  Can I trust Windows 10?  I noticed that this new computer does occasionally turn on its fans when the lid is closed and the power supply is connected, so I am not sure if I can trust it ... I don't know if it will also do it with the power supply disconnected. For now I try to manually hibernate it, just in case.

Comment: I've been using a Mac with an SSD for a few years so I got into the habit of just closing the lid and putting it in my bag ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to just close the lid before carrying a computer around in a bag?

You can set the action that happens when you close the lid. Setting it to hibernation will hibernate your pc the same way as if you would do it manually. I don't see any reason why not to do it.

**Sleep:** there is also a setting "hibernate after", it will wake up the pc even from sleep and hibernate it. Again it doesn't depend on whether you sent your pc manually or by closing the lid.
Some laptop's has functionality to detect when they're moved and stop HDD (hp calls it "driver guard"). So for those laptop normal carrying shouldn't cause any problem (worst case could happen is that the battery drains totally if you constantly shake it and it can't hibernate).
If you have anything other set to wake up laptop (wireless mouse, installation...) those will of course wake it up from sleep.

I've also a Windows 7 laptop, I set "hibernate after" to 2 hours, I carry it sleeping during the day and I hibernate it for the night.

Comment: As a little side note, I always allow my 7200rpm HDD to spin down before moving my laptop, while most systems are able to withstand movement while operating there's no harm in caution, particularly if your primary drive is a spinning hard drive.

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that while some laptops may keep the HDD off reliably, in general Windows still cannot be trusted and there's no guarantees of reliability.

Comment: "in general Windows "  I don't think such a thing exists. By default many things can wake up your pc, so in that context I agree with you: laptop can wake up during carry. If you don't want / don't have time to check all the settings and prevent it, then safest way is to always hibernate it while carrying.

Comment: I was asking because I found OS X to be very reliable in this respect. If it's not plugged in, it won't wake up, and closing the lid is perfectly sufficient.  By "in general" I meant that "*not all* Windows laptops will stay off reliably".  I'll accept your answer tomorrow.